# Call a generic method ensuring where

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method, on the base of T type I need to call a stricter generic method, how can I do it without reflections? In the example I used **as** that is obviusly wrong

```
public T foo1<T>()
{
   if(T is IMyInterface)
   {
     return SpecificMethod<T as IMyInterface>();      
   } 
}

private T SpecificMethod<T>() where T : IMyInterface 
{
// IMyInterface specific implementation
}

private T GenericMethod<T>() 
{
// something generic to do
}
```

Comment: You can't, I'm afraid. It's just not supported by C#. I'd either have two methods (one with the constraint and one not) or use reflection.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Feels like a X-Y problem.

Comment: What would your expected `T` be in this sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it this way:

```
public interface IMyInterface { }

public T Foo1<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(IMyInterface))
    {
        return (T)SpecificMethod<IMyInterface>();
    }

    return default(T);
}

private T SpecificMethod<T>() where T : IMyInterface
{
    return default(T);
}

private T GenericMethod<T>()
{
    return default(T);
}
```

What you asked for, can't just be done.

Comment: `if (typeof(T) == typeof(IMyInterface))`: won't work, `(T)SpecificMethod<IMyInterface>();` dangerous.

Comment: Thank you but, I can't use this one because I need the T type.